# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/com.asdmt.bean.DiagramManagerManagedBean not found in context "java:"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, websphere-6.1

I ran into a little problem. I try to use a viewScoped managedBean in one of my page. I proced as follow:

My bean location

[image]

my bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "diagramManager")
@ViewScoped
public class DiagramManagerManagedBean {
    private String toto = "toto";

    public String getToto() {
        return toto;
    }
}
```

but in my page if i try a #{diagramManager.toto}
i've only got an error 500 '**Error 500: Name comp/env/com.asdmt.bean.DiagramManagerManagedBean not found in context "java:"**.
I had already tried to declare the managedbean in my faceconfig.xml i've got the same error.
I'm on wepshere 6.1 usign JSF2

Full stack trace

```
 [17/02/16 09:50:45:816 CET] 0000002e ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Exception non interceptée émise par une des méthodes de service du servlet : Faces Servlet. Exception : javax.servlet.ServletException: Name comp/env/com.asdmt.bean.DiagramManagerManagedBean not found in context "java:".
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1223)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1158)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at usinor.web.A2CSecurityFilter.doFilter(A2CSecurityFilter.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:850)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:693)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:656)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:535)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3673)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1560)
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/com.asdmt.bean.DiagramManagerManagedBean not found in context "java:".
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1767)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1083)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:991)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1263)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:145)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:363)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.lookupFieldResource(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AllAnnotationLifecycleProvider.checkFieldAnnotation(AllAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:83)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.checkAnnotation(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:139)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.processAnnotations(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:100)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider.newInstance(NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:91)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:333)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:296)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:179)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:99)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:158)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:219)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:131)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:45)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:46)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:505)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1981)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1223)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1158)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at usinor.web.A2CSecurityFilter.doFilter(A2CSecurityFilter.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:850)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:693)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:656)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:535)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3673)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1560)

[17/02/16 09:50:45:831 CET] 0000002e WebApp        E   [Servlet Error]-[Faces Servlet]: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/com.asdmt.bean.DiagramManagerManagedBean not found in context "java:".
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1767)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1083)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:991)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1263)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:145)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:363)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.lookupFieldResource(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AllAnnotationLifecycleProvider.checkFieldAnnotation(AllAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:83)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.checkAnnotation(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:139)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.processAnnotations(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:100)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider.newInstance(NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:91)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:333)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:296)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:179)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:99)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:158)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:219)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:131)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:45)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:46)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:505)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1981)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1223)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1158)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at usinor.web.A2CSecurityFilter.doFilter(A2CSecurityFilter.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:850)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:693)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:656)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:535)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3673)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1560)
```

**EDIT** : as balusc said i was not runing the corect code

Comment: Could you please share your whole directory ? Do you have a xml configuration file ?

Comment: Stack trace tells it happened while processing a field which is marked with `@Resource` annotation. You didn't show that culprit anywhere. In other words, it occurred during building the managed bean (so it's successfully found!)

Comment: @BalusC I don't have any `@Ressource in` my code :/ realy just that simple managedBean (well i made it that simple to find where the problem was but it's still here)

Comment: Apparently you're not running the code you think you're running. Stack traces don't lie. Clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart, etc.

Comment: @BalusC ok rookie mistake ! It was not the good code but with the new i still have an error working on it thanks !